# Import the project from github into Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I use Android Studio just two month and trying to import project from github into Android Studio in Windows 8 for the first time. Could you please explaine how to do it?
I'm trying to import the project
https://github.com/mapsme/omim

and use doc from
https://github.com/mapsme/omim/blob/master/docs/INSTALL.md

I have Android Studio in Windows 8 and download NDK as specified in

> **Android**. Install Android SDK and NDK, place these somewhere easy to type.

and unzip in C:\Program Files\Android\android-ndk-r12b

But I don't understand how to

> run ./set_up_android.py

in Windows 8

*Explain, please, how to import the project.* What I have to do to run project by Android Studio in emulator or device?

Comment: If you already have android studio set up you can do 
File -> Open -> navigate to project folder and open it.

Comment: I get a lot of errors when open, import or run project. Errors with gradle, or, for example, MwmActivity.java: "cannot resolve symbol.." etc.
What folder I have to import: "omim-android" or  "omim" folder?

Comment: @Aerim  I have to install Git or I can work without git?

Comment: Could you try to import the project omim or omim/android (I don't understand which folder I should import) ? And you can see many errors.

Comment: Now I get error

D:\Android\android\build.gradle
Error:(29, 0) Could not read script 'D:\Android\android\secure.properties' as it does not exist.

Comment: You should be importing omim/android/
I'm looking into the other error

Comment: hi, did you able to import the project